# Tabulator and App Script Tutorial save function not working

Tags: google-apps-script, tabulator

Good morning. I am working to build a web app using tabulator and appscripts with a google sheet "database" I guess you would call it. I found a tutorial online and have been following along. There have been a few issues that I have been able to find and fix. However; right now I am working to build the functionality where if you change the web app the google sheet updates in the background. I have (as far as I can tell) followed the tutorial exactly but can't seem to get the functionality to work. I have listed the code below and would appreciate any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sequencing Webb App Test</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
  
  <div id="jsData"></div>
  <div id="alerts"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

      <script>

        const elements = {}
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", pageLoad)

        function pageLoad(){
         elements.alerts = document.getElementById("alerts")
          loadData();
        }

        function loadData(){
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler((jsData) => {
            // if data successfully return
            const table = new Tabulator("#jsData", {
            layout:"fitDataTable",
            //height: 300, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
            data:jsData, //assign data to table
            layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
            pagination: true,
            paginationSize: 25,
            paginationSizeSelector:[5, 10, 50],
            paginationCounter:"rows",
            columns:[ //Define Table Columns
            {title:"Date", field:"Date"},
            {title:"Requester", field:"Requester"},
            {title:"Customer", field:"Customer"},
            {title:"Issue Summary", field:"Issue Summar"},
            {title:"Additional Information", field:"Additional Information"},
            {title:"Indy", field:"Indy"},
            {title:"Indy Action", field:"Indy Action"},
            {title:"RDO", field:"RDO"},
            {title:"RDO Action", field:"RDO Action"},
            {title:"Capetown", field:"CTAction"},
            {title:"Status", field:"Status"},
            {title:"Condition", field:"Condition", width:50, editor:"list", editorParams: {values: ["New","In progress","Complete"]}},
            {title:"ID", field:"ID", width:20,hozAlign:"center"},
            ],
          })

          // trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
          // table.on("rowClick", function(e, row){ 
          // alert("Row " + row.getData().Customer + " Clicked!!!!");
          // })


          table.on("cellEditied", function(cell){

              const id = cell._cell.row.data.ID
              const val = cell._cell.value
              const field = cell._cell.column.field

              // if the codition column is updated in the web app activate the if statement
              if(field === "Condition"){
                elements.alerts.textContent = "Saving Changes..."
                google.script.run
                .withSuccessHandler(() => {
                  elements.alerts.textContent = "Change Saved!"
                })
                .withFailureHandler((er) => {
                  elements.alerts.textContent = "Error Saving Changes!"
                })
                .editID({id: id, val: val});
              }
          })   
            // end if data successfully returned
          })
          .withFailureHandler((er) => {

          })
          .getData()
        }

          // var tabledata = [
          // {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
          // {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
          // {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
          // {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
          // {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
          // ];


      </script>



  </body>
</html>
```

```
function getData() {
  const mainSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const mainSheet = mainSS.getSheetByName('Data');
  const dataRange = mainSheet.getRange('A1').getDataRegion();
  const displayDataRange = dataRange.getDisplayValues();

  const headers = displayDataRange.shift();

  // console.log(headers);
  // console.log(dataRange);

  const jsData = displayDataRange.map(r => {
    const tempObject = {};

    headers.forEach((header, i) => {
        tempObject[header] = r[i]
    })
        return tempObject
  })
      console.log(jsData)
        return jsData
    
}
// End of getData function

function editID(props){
  const mainSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const mainSheet = mainSS.getSheetByName('Data');
  const idCellMatch = mainSheet.getRange("N2:N").createTextFinder(props.id).findNext()

  if(idCellMatch === null) throw new Error ("No matching record.")

  const recordRowNumber = idCellMatch.getRow()

  mainSheet.getRange(recordRowNumber, 13).setValue(props.val)
}
```

The expectation of the code is when I update a column (specifically the Condition column) the data will save and be sent back to the google sheet to be saved there as well. Right now, I can bring up the web app table and change the condition column as expected. However; the changes aren't returning to the google sheet to be saved.

Comment: Please do a little debugging yourself and provide us with a little more direction by identifying where the problem is occurring you have a debugger and developer tools please learn how to use them.